# How to play one video file in two videoviews parallel?

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview

I have one video file in raw folder and i want to play this file into two video view parallel. i tried also but in one videoview display perfectly and other display black part in video view.Help me to how can i play one video file in two video view parallel.

**My .java file**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String VIDEO_PATH = "http://hier-gehts-app.de/extern/video/bbb_1080p_30fps_0.mp4";

    private VideoView mVideoView1;
    private VideoView mVideoView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mVideoView1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video1);
        mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video2);

        mVideoView1.setVideoPath(VIDEO_PATH);
        mVideoView2.setVideoPath(VIDEO_PATH);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mVideoView1.start();
        mVideoView2.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        mVideoView1.stopPlayback();
        mVideoView2.stopPlayback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer

If Device supports multiple video playing feature than and than it plays two videos parallel otherwise it gives error like **can't play this file.**

Comment: Thats great.. I was trying to generate your problem in "nexus 5" but i can see that parallel video playback has no issue.. :)

Comment: yes @ChintanRathod 
it will be work on kitkat and above version of android

Comment: please can you give a source of your project